# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::bindShared() in lumen-web-api-oauth-2-authentication

Tags: laravel-5, oauth-2.0, lumen-5.4

I've just installed oauth2 to add Role-based Permissions to my application based on Lumen 5.4 But when I try to execute

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Call to
>   undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::bindShared()

can anyone help me?

Comment: Which oauth library are you using?

Comment: To fix it .i execute `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload -o`